# MongoDB Aggregation query to group the states into regions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need a help with the MongoDB aggregation query for this dataset with over 10000 records.

Each document needs to be grouped into 'South West Region' or 'South East Region' based on its `state`. If `state` is `TX` or `AR`, it will be grouped into 'South West Region'.  If `state` is `GA` or `AL`, it will be grouped into 'South East Region'.

```
[{
  "count": 38,
  "city": "Fort Worth",
  "state": "TX",
  "country": "US"
},{
  "count": 2,
  "city": "Chatsworth",
  "state": "GA",
  "country": "US"
},{
  "count": 32,
  "city": "Round Rock",
  "state": "TX",
  "country": "US"
},{
  "city": "Little Rock",
  "state": "AR",
  "count": 72,
  "country": "US"
},{
  "count": 34,
  "city": "Theodore",
  "state": "AL",
  "country": "US"
}
.
.
.
]
```

How do I proceed with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `$group` operator in the aggregation pipeline. The `_id` field can be set as 'South West Region' or 'South East Region' using conditional operators like `$switch` or `$cond`. Other fields can be set by using the `$push` operator.

Here's a working Mongoplayground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tLQjBnDicIl)

Answer (score 0):

Here is official Docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Also make sure to add indexes, so your aggregation doesn't take forever

Comment: I have tried this. But I am unable to frame the query.